# Web scraping with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda

I have a Python scraping script I wish to run on AWS Lambda, to save on EC2 costs. However, the script also requires PhantomJS, oauth2client, PYOpenSSL, selenium and of course, Beautiful Soup to complete it's scraping.

Is it possible to run Beautiful Soup (by running the additional required programs above too) on AWS Lambda?

Comment: Side-note: AWS Lambda functions have a 5-minute execution limit, which might make it unsuitable for scraping. You should consider using [Amazon EC2 spot instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) to reduce your costs for this type of non-urgent workload.

Comment: Cheers John. Do you know if it is possible to add additional modules though such as PhantomJS, Beautiful Soup etc if within the first 2 mins of execution time say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a deployment package, which would be automatically copied onto the Lambda environment prior to your function being called.

See: [Creating a Deployment Package (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)